# End a else if statement C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I didn't know what else to use in this case but an if statement.

What I am trying to do is I am getting a value `string direction;` from a Windows form and checking if it has the value I am looking for. Then checking if the `turtleDir` which is a string value indicating the direction `turtleDir` has.

The problem comes here at else if statements, when the `turtleDir` is `lookingleft` it does all of the else if statements. What I want it to do is after it has done that else if statement it needs to stop and wait for the next command. not go through all the statements.

Can someone please advise me on how to fix it and what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
else if ( Program.form.direction == "right" ) 
{
   if ( turtleDir == "left" )
   {
      angle = -1.6f;
      turtleDir = "lookingLeft";
      Program.form.direction = "";
   }
   else if ( turtleDir == "lookingLeft" )
   {
      angle = 3.15f;
      turtleDir = "lookingDown";
   }
   else if ( turtleDir == "lookingDown" )
   {
      angle = 1.6f;
      turtleDir = "lookingRight";
   }
   else if ( turtleDir == "lookingRight" )
   {
      angle = 0.0f;
      turtleDir = "lookingUp";   
   }
}
```

Comment: You can `switch` on strings in C#, and this method seems like a good candidate. :) But you could also think about switching to enum for directions.

Comment: It's not possible for all the _else if_ statements to run. What's probably happening is that your main loop (which we can't see in your post) continues to run, so it then hits the `if...else` code again and again, going through lookingLeft->lookingDown->lookingRight->lookingUp, at which point none of the conditions in the `if...else` can be matched. Your bug is in the "stop and wait". How is your program stopping and waiting for the next command?

Comment: you are rightabout it keep looping, i had the same problem yesterday on a keypress, im developing in XNA and its in the update method. so  dont know where the stop or wait is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement on strings, too:

```
switch (turtleDir) {
    case "left":
        angle = -1.6f;
        turtleDir = "lookingLeft";
        Program.form.direction = "";
        break;
    case "lookingLeft":
        angle = 3.15f;
        turtleDir = "lookingDown";
        break;
    // other cases
}
```

This way, the `switch` block is always exited after your instructions are done. You can also specify what to do when the string matches none of these values by adding a `case default:` at the end. Remember each of these cases needs to be terminated by a `break` statement (or `return`/`throw` but i don't think you need those in this case).

If still every case is executed, your problem lies somewhere else. If a method contains this code and is called starting with e.g. `turtleDir == "left"`, each successive call of the method will let `turtleDir` cycle until every case has been executed and `turtleDir` ends up with the final value `"lookingUp"`. So look at your control flow and maybe keep track whether you already performed this check. Maybe keep track of the elapsed time and change `turtleDir` only if it has been in a particular state for a while (i don't know your requirements).

**EDIT:** You should set `Program.form.direction = ""` in every `case` statement. That's why your code gets executed over and over again. Also, if no direction is entered, clear it, too.

Comment: still does the same, it isnt exiting :(

Comment: @Sigh-AniDe Then your problem lies elsewhere. With this code, only one case will be executed for sure. i think the method containing that code might get called multiple times. Have you checked for that?

Comment: its in xna therefore being called multipe times, as it is in the update method, but how do i stop it?

Comment: @Sigh-AniDe I don't know your requirements, but you need to somehow keep track of what you have done. Maybe store the last time you switched direction and only recheck it after a period of time has elapsed.

Comment: its a text based game so the direction only changes when the user types "right" and presses the enter button.

Comment: @Sigh-AniDe then you should store input and actual direction in separate variables

Comment: they are in seperate variables, input is set in `string direction` and actualDirection is stored in `string turtleDir`

Comment: @Sigh-AniDe Found it. You're not resetting `Program.form.direction`, so in every update your loop thinks the user had entered a direction again. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks botz3000! cant believe i didn't see that. Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty `return;`- Statement, but then you leave your method too...

Comment: It doesnt work, it still goes thorugh all the else if statements

Comment: you have to put the `return;` into each case

Comment: i did put the return into each case

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch

```
switch (turtleDir)
{
    case "left":
        angle = -1.6f;
        turtleDir = "lookingLeft";
        Program.form.direction = "";
        break;

    case "lookingLeft":
        angle = 3.15f;
        turtleDir = "lookingDown";
        break;

    case "lookingDown":
        angle = 1.6f;
        turtleDir = "lookingRight";
        break;

    case "lookingRight":
        angle = 0.0f;
        turtleDir = "lookingUp";   
        break;

    default:
        // Optional, but place any actions if non of the above is matched
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **something else** going on here....

Only one branch of an IF/ELSE-IF statement will be executed.  You might want to refactor to a SWITCH statement for readability reasons; but **not because it would change your behaviour**.

Look at this code:

```
    if(0 == 0) { Console.WriteLine("Branch 1"); }
    else if(true==true) { Console.WriteLine("Branch 2"); }
    else if(false==false) { Console.WriteLine("Branch 3"); }
```

ALL of the conditions are true.  And the first one executes.  ONLY the first one.

In this code - only the second two are true:
        if(0 == 2) { Console.WriteLine("Branch 1"); }
        else if(true==true) { Console.WriteLine("Branch 2"); }
        else if(false==false) { Console.WriteLine("Branch 3"); }

And ONLY the second one executes.

A series of else-if's won't all execute if the condition is true.

My *guess* is that you are looping through this really fast or something and the next iteration is entering the IF logic and executing the next branch.  You might need to post more code so that you get more helpful answers for your particular situation.

The best way to track this down, IMHO, is to just place a breakpoint on the start of your IF logic and step-through the code one execution at a time.  You should see that it only goes into one ELSE-IF branch and exits, and you can see if/why it re-enters.

Finally, the SWITCH statement doesn't allow you to implicitly execute multiple branches either.

```
    switch(test)
    {
        case "one":
            Console.WriteLine("Branch 1");
        case "two":
            Console.WriteLine("Branch 2");
    }
```

That won't even compile.  I believe in C/C++ you could fall though case statements unless you explicitly added break; or similar control statement.  In C# that's not the case.